# Как отправить сообщение от пользователя, которое он вводит в телеграм-боте, на почту(telebot)?

Tags: python, telebot, бот

Есть небольшая проблема. Пытаюсь понять как отправлять сообщения от пользователя, что он ввёл в боте телеграмма, на почту конкретному человеку. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого в питоне есть библиотека smtib, но есть загвоздка; для отправки почты нужна сама почта с собакой, данные для соединения(сервер и порт)*, например, чтобы отправить сообщение на почту, и у отправителя почта gmail, то сервер будет smtp.gmail.com, порт 587
Пример использования библиотеки есть на youtube: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvAGL0EDLVY, если будете следовать гайду, то вот еще одно(гугл изменил доступ сторонних приложений к почте с 2022года): https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RyoTETtvoFQ
По-другому(без пароля от почты отправителя и протоколов) не получится
*в интернете просто забиваете: smtp <почта которая нужна, например gmail> server setting